# How to bind the Textblock.Text to a list Count or Sum methods?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is it possible to Bind TextBlock.Text to ObservableCollection to get Count() or Sum(x=>x.price) ?

```
     productList= new ObservableCollection<productClass>();
    <TextBlock Name="SumPrice" Text="{Binding productList.Sum(x=>x.price) ??}" />
    <TextBlock Name="CountProducts" Text="{Binding productList.Count() ??}" />
```

Thanks!

@EDIT:

ViewModel:

```
     public class ParagonClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
         (...) private objects(...)

//public objects start
            public int PdID
            {
                get
                {
                    return _pdID;
                }
                set
                {
                    _pdID = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("PdID");
                }
            }

//public objects end (there is lot of objects, so I didn't copy them all)


       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

myWindow.xaml

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="productsLV" >
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Boolean2Visibility" />
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
(...)
```

Listview has itemssource binded to observablecollection like:

myWindow.xaml.cs

```
                productsList = new ObservableCollection<ParagonClass>(); 
                productsLV.ItemsSource = productsList;
```

So my ObservableCollection is creating in window as public. To get sum and count in my class i need to get that collection but without static i think its not possible.

Comment: You can create a property that can return the value you need I guess (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978473/wpf-how-to-bind-to-a-nested-property for possible issues)

Comment: Ok, understand. But my Datamodel is class which doesn't contains ObservableCollection. I'm creating it on another window, so dont really have access to productList. As answered in last comment - should I rather create static ObservableCollection and use count/sum in datamodel or any other way?

Comment: Use a property that handle the value, if the ObservableCollection is initialized, return the value, if not return 0 or -1 ? (show us the source code of your model that we can help you)

Comment: class and xaml/xaml.cs added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an `int` property in your view model that returns it:

```
public int Sum { get { return productList.Sum(x => x.Price); } }
```

Then your binding can be:

```
<TextBlock Name="SumPrice" Text="{Binding Sum}" />
```

You could do the same with your `count` property.

Comment: Ok, i'll try those answers. One more question - I have class as my DataModel, so I should rather create ObservableCollection as static in this class or as public non static in my window where I'm using class?

Comment: @user13657 I don't see a reason why you would use `static` in this case. I'd make it public non-static.

Comment: Well I guess that's helpful, but at this momment Im wonder how to use this count/sum fields so I can get value from another window. Check first post please, which explains more.

Comment: If you're trying to access it through another window, then yes. I'd make it static. I misread what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Linq queries in binding expressions, so you need to expose the sum as a property.

`Count` is already a property, so you don't need the Linq `Count()` method. Just bind to `productList.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise binding it to a property in the ViewModel that returns the correct count,

```
public int ProductCount
{
    get { return productList.Count(); }
}
```

You can then do,

```
<TextBlock Name="CountProducts" Text="{Binding ProductCount}" />
```

And do make sure that when the `productList` changes, you raise the event to notify the view that it needs to update the `ProductCount` property,

```
this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductCount"));
```