# Change of subitem in WPF CustomControl Style?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have a CustomControl which contains among other things a DataGrid. One time I use this CustomControl I need to do a small change to the appearance of the DataGrid CellStyle.

What I am doing right now is Duplicating my whole CustomControl Style in XAML just to change the CellStyle. So I would like to keep my base cell style and only overwrite the DataGrid CellStyle. Therefore, I need to somehow access the DataGrid, is that possible?

Simplified Style for the CustomControl (DataGridCustomControl)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}">
                <DataGrid x:Name="part_datagrid" ItemsSource ="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}}}"
                <!-- some stuff which is always the same included here -->
                </DataGrid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I would like to do now is trying to change the properties of the datagrid in another Style.  Essentially, something like shown below, which I could not get to work. (DataGridCellStyle1 not included here for abbreviation).

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCustomControl1"  TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}}">
    <Setter Property="DataGridCellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}"/>
</Style>
```

I actually don't have a clue if this may be achievable via ControlTemplates, but I wasn't able to get it on my own. So right now I'm not even sure, it is possible to access my `part_datagrid`.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCustomControl1"  TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <!-- Implementation missing-->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083454/1506454 - similar to how DataGrid has CellStyle and RowStyle properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `DataGridCellStyle` [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property) of type `Style` to your `DataGridCustomControl` class and bind to it in the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridCustomControl}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="part_datagrid" CellStyle="{TemplateBinding DataGridCellStyle}" 
              ItemsSource ="...">
                <!-- some stuff which is always the same included here -->
    </DataGrid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can then set the `DataGridCellStyle` using a style setter, just like you would set any other dependency property.

Comment: Thank you. That's a smart approach for me. I'll definitly stick to that approach.  For anyone else who stumbles about this,  I recommend the thread ASh mentioned (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083454/1506454), as also different approaches are shown.