# WPF binding ADUser doesn't update TextBox

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding

I have a WPF GUI to show AD-objects loaded and operated through PowerShell.

The GUI works as planned, but some bindings does not update their controls (mainly TextBoxes). Some controls does however work without any problem.

I get the data through the Get-AD* cmdlets and it gets stored directly in the DataContext of a Grid higher up in the hierarchy. The properties I want to list are added to the cmdlet call with `-Properties "EmailAddress", ...`. I have also tried `-Properties *`, but the bindings still doesn't update.

I suspect that only the properties that are inherited from the baseobject, works with the bindings. But I can be totaly of on this.

I have tried:

- different settings for the binding, i.e. NotifyOnSourceUpdate...
- separating the properties through `Select-Object EmailAddress, ...`, but this breaks it all and no controls are shown
- using a test object (PSCustomObject) with the necessary properties, this also break the controls
- if I assign the values directly in code, the textboxes show the correct info, i.e. `$syncHash.tbUserotherTelephone.Text = $syncHash.gridObjInfo.DataContext.otherTelephone`

For the example below, the object that is put in `$syncHash.gridBaseInfoUser.DataContext` is of type ADUser (BaseType: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount)

Exampel of how the object the bindings are sourced from, is retrieved

```
$syncHash.gridObjInfo.DataContext = Get-ADUser $this.SelectedItem -Properties "EmailAddress", ...
```

`$this.SelectedItems` is the selected item in a DataGrid. I have verified that the correct data is retrieved at both Get-ADUser

Xaml hierarchy, showing two controls, one that gets the TextBox.Text entered, one that doesn't. Some code is omitted to save space.

```xml
<Window>
 <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
  ...
  <Grid x:Name="gridMainInfo" Grid.Row="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="Auto">
   <Grid x:Name="gridObjInfo">
    <Grid.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="PropValueStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" Value="">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
       </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
<!-- Other grids for other objectclasses -->
    <Grid x:Name="gridBaseInfoUser" Grid.Row="{DynamicResource TypeObjInfoRowLoc}">
     <Grid.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjectClass}" Value="user">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
       </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
<!-- This binding apparently does not work, so the textbox is empty -->
    <Border Style="{StaticResource PropBorder}" Grid.Row="5">
     <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource PropTitleWidth}"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource PropValueWidth}"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock x:Name="tblUserotherTelephone" Style="{StaticResource PropTitleStyle}"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="tbUserotherTelephone" Style="{StaticResource PropValueStyle}" Text="{Binding otherTelephone}"/>
     </Grid>
    </Border>
<!-- This binding apparently does work, so the textbox gets its Text set to the UserPrincipalName -->
    <Border Style="{StaticResource PropBorder}" Grid.Row="6">
     <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource PropTitleWidth}"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource PropValueWidth}"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock x:Name="tblUserUserPrincipalName" Style="{StaticResource PropTitleStyle}"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="tbUserUserPrincipalName" Style="{StaticResource PropValueStyle}" Text="{Binding UserPrincipalName}"/>
     </Grid>
    </Border>
   </Grid>
...
</Window>
```

Comment: Does adding brackets `Text="{Binding [otherTelephone]}"` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. When setting DataContext, I get error "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Item' of type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser'."
Switching to Mode=OneWay, the textboxes gets "(Collection)" as Text.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, I would like to help you but have no experience with `wpf`. I developed a `winform` app that might have the same use you're looking for. [Link](https://github.com/santysq/SimpleQueryUI).

Comment: `otherTelephone` is not a property directly accessible. You may try to use `{Binding psadapted.otherTelephone}` but this means binding on a nested property. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978473/wpf-how-to-bind-to-a-nested-property) about such binding but I'm not a `wpf` expert.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't psadapted work either.